# Dapper not deserializing nvarchar type

Tags: c#, dapper

Essentially, I have a Playlist object:

```
public class Playlist
{
    public int PlaylistID { get; set; }
    public string PlaylistName { get; set; }
    public string PlaylistUri { get; set; }
    public int FestivalID { get; set; }
}
```

When I attempt to read the data from the database, the PlaylistID and FestivalID data gets populated but PlaylistName/PlaylistUri doesn't. i've checked the data types:

```
COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE
PlaylistID  int
PlaylistName nvarchar
PlaylistUri nvarchar
FestivalID  int
```

Here is also the code to get the data (Very much in alpha, will do clean up when ready)

```
public class SpotifyApiData
{
    private string _connectionString;
    private string ALL_DATA = "SELECT * FROM EdgeCases; SELECT [PlaylistID] ,[PlaylistName],[PlaylistID] FROM Playlist; SELECT * FROM Festival;";
    public string ConnectionString { get => _connectionString; set => _connectionString = value; }


    public SpotifyApiData()
    {
        _connectionString = ConfigurationHelper.GetConnectionString();
    }

    public void GetRefreshablePlaylist()
    {

    }

    public PlaylistCollectionData GetAllData()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var multi = connection.QueryMultiple(ALL_DATA))
            {

                return new PlaylistCollectionData()
                {
                    EdgeCases = multi.Read<EdgeCases>().ToList(),
                    Festivals = multi.Read<Festival>().ToList(),
                    Playlists = multi.Read<Playlist>().ToList()
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading Festival before PlayList. Invert those two lines to match the order of the select query

```
return new PlaylistCollectionData()
{
    EdgeCases = multi.Read<EdgeCases>().ToList(),
    Playlists = multi.Read<Playlist>().ToList(),
    Festivals = multi.Read<Festival>().ToList()
};
```

Also the select for the playlist seems to be incomplete, it should be

```
 SELECT [PlaylistID],[PlaylistName],[PlaylistUri],[FestivalID] FROM Playlist;
```

Comment: Thank you, that sorted the problem. I didn't think they had to match the ordering but that kind of makes sense. Me just being sloppy. Accepted.